# navigation not work in react native while link one component to another

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, expo

don't know where am I wrong, my react navigation is not working. when I click on search icon it goes to search bar but its not going.  below I shared my code. please check if you any query please free feel to ask.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Home from "./Screens/Home";
import Search from "./Screens/Search";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import VideoPlayer from "./Screens/VideoPlayer";
import Explore from "./Screens/Explore";
import Subscribe from "./Screens/Subscribe";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const RootHome = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === "Home") {
            iconName = "home";
          } else if (route.name === "explorer") {
            iconName = "explore";
          } else if (route.name === "subscribe") {
            iconName = "subscriptions";
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={32} color={color} />;
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "tomato",
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: "gray",
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="explorer"
        component={Explore}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="subscribe"
        component={Subscribe}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="roothome" component={RootHome} />
        <Stack.Screen name="search" component={Search} />
        <Stack.Screen name="videoplayer" component={VideoPlayer} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

> Header.js

This is header.js file where I navigate the search icon but its not working. i install react navigation still its not working.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { AntDesign, Ionicons, MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


export default Header = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: 45,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        elevation: 4,
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", margin: 5 }}>
        <AntDesign
          name="youtube"
          size={28}
          color="red"
          style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
        />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 5, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          YouTube
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          width: 150,
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          margin: 5,
        }}
      >
        <Ionicons name="md-videocam" size={30} color="black" />
        {/* <Ionicons name="notifications-outline" size={30} color="black" /> */}
        <FontAwesome
          name="search"
          size={30}
          color="black"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("search")}
        />
        <MaterialIcons name="account-circle" size={30} color="black" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

> Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Header from "../Components/Header";
import Card from "../Components/Card";

export default HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Header />
      <ScrollView>
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't see the `Header` component as a screen in your `Stack.Navigator`. Under which navigator did you add it?

Comment: @TarunSharma I have wrapped the header component inside the Home component.

Comment: And the `Home` component is only inside the `TabNavigator`, right? Not inside the `StackNavigator`?